# ABCPDF Converting Text PDF to Image PDF with correct layout

Tags: c#, pdf, abcpdf, abcpdf9

I am trying to convert a text pdf to image pdf, and for that I found the following article:

[ABCpdf convert text to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414887/abcpdf-convert-text-to-image)

So I took the code an produced the following code:

```
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc firstDoc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc();
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc secondDoc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc();

firstDoc.Read(@"C:\pdf1.pdf");

for (int i = 1; i <= firstDoc.PageCount; i++)
{
    secondDoc.Page = secondDoc.AddPage();
    firstDoc.PageNumber = i;
    secondDoc.MediaBox.String = firstDoc.MediaBox.String;

    using (Bitmap bm = firstDoc.Rendering.GetBitmap())
    {
        secondDoc.AddImageBitmap(bm, false);
    }
}

secondDoc.Save(@"c:\pdf2.pdf");
```

Now the code above works well except when I have pdf documents that have some page in portrait layout and other pages in landscape.  What ends happening is the following:

let's say that I have a pdf document that has;

```
Page 1 - portrait
Page 2 - landscape
Page 3 - portrait
Page 4 - portrait
```

The result that this code is producing is:

```
Page 1 - portrait
Page 2 - portrait
Page 3 - landscape
Page 4 - portrait
```

Is there anything else that I would need to do other than setting the `MediaBox` to have the correct outcome?

Comment: Have you tried putting `secondDoc.Page = secondDoc.AddPage();` after `secondDoc.MediaBox.String = firstDoc.MediaBox.String;`?

Comment: @mkl I tried... that did not work neither.

Comment: You probably need to detect the rotation of each page in firstDoc and apply the same to secondDoc. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572165/detect-orientation-of-every-page-in-a-pdf-using-abcpdf

Comment: @mkl your solution was correct.  I was not clear on what should have come first.  Please add an answer, and I will accept it.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the helpful feedback in the comments, I was able to solve the problem by putting

```
secondDoc.Page = secondDoc.AddPage();
```

after

```
secondDoc.MediaBox.String = firstDoc.MediaBox.String;
```

The working code now looks like this:

```
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc firstDoc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc();
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc secondDoc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.Doc();

firstDoc.Read(@"C:\pdf1.pdf");

for (int i = 1; i <= firstDoc.PageCount; i++)
{
    firstDoc.PageNumber = i;
    secondDoc.MediaBox.String = firstDoc.MediaBox.String;
    secondDoc.Page = secondDoc.AddPage();

    using (Bitmap bm = firstDoc.Rendering.GetBitmap())
    {
        secondDoc.AddImageBitmap(bm, false);
    }
}

secondDoc.Save(@"c:\pdf2.pdf");
```